# ASP.NET WebApi AngularJS tester

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I need some help cause I'm looking for an easy html file using AngularJS so I can do different WebApi calls and see results, statuscode, and time of start-end... but I can't find any good and easy sample over Internet, just some using WepApi2 or Jquery... It will fantastic if someone knows anything because I'm really lost on this issue and need to test lot of WebAPi calls to try to find what's wrong in my app... Any help would really be apreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) to do your tests?
I mean you will never find a HTML file which will exactly call your API.
I do all my WebApi tests with Postman.

Comment: Many thanks Andre, I'll take a look to this REST client. Anyway the main idea was to integrate in our app using our controller/repository functions andalso to simulate concurrent calls ... I don't know if this feature is supported on Postman but I'll investigate right now and try to speak with my boss :) Thx for this fantastic idea ;)

Comment: for you backend it doesn't matters who calls your API. Postman does the same as if you call it with a HTML site. As long as you don't need the view. If you then need more information from the request it self you can see the request with [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: Your answer was really helpfull Andre, just one more question... it's possible with this tools making more than 1 asynchronous call to the WebApi? Thx.

Comment: I'm note sure if I understand it correct. You can make as many calls as you want. Or do you mean make muliple calls at the same time? Can you please mark my answer as correct in this case?

Comment: Many thx, finally Postman did the job. I wanted to make multiple calls so I discovered that there's a collection runner. Many thanks for your time and patience.U're great!!!